# Understanding the tsCV function in R

Tags: r, validation, time-series, modeling

I am having trouble understanding how the tsCV function works. When I use the following code on my data.

```
    > far1 <- function(x, h){forecast(auto.arima(x), h=h)}
    > tsCV(NewQTRS,far1,h=1)
```

I get

```
           Qtr1       Qtr2       Qtr3       Qtr4
    1  350667.00  144882.50  415210.33 -307869.25
    2  147499.60  121431.33  459959.00 -218848.88
    3  -27080.00   13915.00  -12479.00  -63671.50
    4  -40103.89  -22359.41  -91162.51 -111829.08
    5   59024.00  -92397.00  151926.00   15270.58
    6    NA
```

Why do I get an NA for the final value? My understanding, which is clearly wrong, is that the function uses (Year 1 Qtr 1) to predict (Year 1 Qtr 2), and then (Year 1 Qtr 1) (Year 1 Qtr 2) to predict (Year 1 Qtr 3), and etc so the training set would keep building and predicting the next Qtr using all previous available qtrs. This would mean that the first value would be NA and the last value should be the error of a prediction based on the previous 20 qtrs.

Clearly this isn't the case, so can someone explain to me what is actually happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

tsCV returns the error between the forecasted h-step ahead value and the actual value. On the very last data point, there are no more future actual values to compare to, so NA is returned.